# How to detect the combination of alpha and number together in string?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wish to detect all the combination of alpha and number together in string.

For example,

http://www.suleymanmemnun.com/~zeedee/9a70c0acdb2584924f5d0/web.php?#//uk/cgi-bin/confirm.php?cmd=login-submit&dispatch=0ec5d97d42ff8ff75e46c02a034bdf3bb4bf53c0db18fd85h0a134

in the above url, i want to split into part by '/', then detect whether that part contain the combination of number and alpha. if yes then 1, else 0

```
www.suleymanmemnun.com--->0
~zeedee---->0
9a70c0acdb2584924f5d0---->1
web.php?#----->0
```

Comment: It seems the given sample is all alpha and number. What's the output you are expecting? Or is the given string the output?

Comment: hi, i have edited the question as above~

Comment: So, let me ask again, what exactly is the output you expect? That string `'9a70c0acdb2584924f5d0'` only?

Comment: actually i got 1000 URL like the above ones to check, if that url contain those combination of alpha and number together, then will return 1, else -1. for example, www.google.com return -1. the sample as above will return 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB has an in-built function [**`isstrprop`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html) to detect parts of a string that are either alphabet or numeric digit. The syntax is:

`A = isstrprop(input_string, 'alphanum')`

This is used here on each part of the split URL string.

**Code**

```
%//url_string is the given URL string

s1 = regexp(url_string,'/','Split');
out = any(cellfun(@all,isstrprop(s1(~cellfun(@isempty,s1)),'alphanum')))
```

**Explanation**

To understand the code, let's break it down into parts -

```
%// Input URL string
url_string = 'http://www.suleymanmemnun.com/~zeedee/9a70c0acdb2584924f5d0/web.php?#//uk/cgi-bin/confirm.php?cmd=login-submit&dispatch=0ec5d97d42ff8ff75e46c02a034bdf3bb4bf53c0db18fd85h0a134'

%// Split into parts based on '/'
split1 = regexp(url_string,'/','Split');

%// Remove the empty split parts 
out_parts = split1(~cellfun(@isempty,split1))
```

We will get -

```
out_parts = 

    'http:'    'www.suleymanmemnun.com'    '~zeedee'    '9a70c0acdb2584924f5d0'    'web.php?#'    'uk'    'cgi-bin'

    'confirm.php?cmd=login-submit&dispatch=0ec5d97d42ff8ff75e46c02a034bdf3bb4bf53c0db18fd85h0a134'
```

Next, we use `isstrprop` on each of the URL parts -

```
out_detects = cellfun(@all,isstrprop(out_parts,'alphanum'))
```

It gives -

```
out_detects =

     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

Finally, since you are looking to find `any` such combination, we would use `any` command to get the final output -

```
out = any(out_detects)
```

The final answer is `1`.

**Multiple URL strings case**

If you have a file that contains all the URL strings that you would like to test out for the mentioned title of the question, use this -

```
%// url_strings_filepath is the file that contains all the URLs line by line 
url_string_array = importdata(url_strings_filepath);

out = false(1,numel(url_string_array));
for k = 1:numel(url_string_array)
    s1 = regexp(char(url_string_array(k)),'/','Split');
    out(k) = any(cellfun(@all,isstrprop(s1(~cellfun(@isempty,s1)),'alphanum')));
end
disp(out)
```

Comment: Hey! What's that `isstrprop`? +1 for that!

Comment: for alphanum detection! :)

Comment: But are you using it correctly? In the example URL I get `s1{4}` equal to `~zeedee` and your `cellfun` gives `1` in the fourth index. It should be `0` as `s1{4}` contains letters but no numbers. Right?

Comment: Well I have `'http:'    'www.suleymanmemnun.com'    '~zeedee' ...`, so  that ~zeedee is third which is 0 for me. `s1` still has some empty cells, which I am removing in the next line, that might have confused you maybe?

Comment: Yes, that was it. I was counting the empty cells. I hadn't noticed you are removing them

Comment: how about i gt 700 data, and i use "url_string=importdata('DATA/URLs/training_URL')", it return me the error as below "??? Error using ==> isstrprop
Unexpected data type.

Error in ==> Untitled at 15
out_detects =
cellfun(@all,isstrprop(out_parts,'alphanum'))
 "

Comment: @user3340270 What do you have under that - `'DATA/URLs/training_URL'`? What exactly is it? A text files of URL strings?

Comment: @user3340270 Check out added **Multiple URL strings case**!

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming you want to detect parts that contain one or more letters, one or more numbers, and possibly other characters too**:

```
parts = regexp(str,'/+','split'); %// divide strings into parts
result = cellfun(@(p) ~isempty(regexp(p,'[a-z_A-Z]')) & ~isempty(regexp(p,'\d')), parts);
```

With your example URL this gives:

```
parts = 
    http:
    www.suleymanmemnun.com
    ~zeedee
    9a70c0acdb2584924f5d0
    web.php?#
    uk
    cgi-bin
    confirm.php?cmd=login-submit&dispatch=0ec5d97d42ff8ff75e46c02a034bdf3bb4bf53c0db18fd85h0a134

result =
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
```

To determine if at least one of the parts of the string contains what you want: use `any(result)`. In the example that would be `1`.

---

**Assuming you want to detect parts that contain any combination of letters and numbers, and no other characters**:

```
parts = regexp(str,'/+','split'); %// divide strings into parts
result = cellfun(@(p) numel(regexp(p,'[a-z_A-Z_0-9]'))==numel(p) , parts)
```

In your example:

```
result =
    0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: yes,actually i got 1000 URL like the above ones to check, if that url contain those combination of alpha and number together, then will return 1, else -1. for example, www.google.com return -1. the sample as above will return 1. How about i count the "result", if got 1 then at the end those url output is 1, else 0

Comment: @user3340270 I think your intended final output is, in my code, `any(result)`: this  gives 1 if there are numbers and letters within the same part of the string